# Vercel Deployment: Firebase Configuration Environment Variables Undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vercel

I'm having trouble deploying my React application on Vercel. I'm using Firebase in my application and I've set up the environment variables for my firebase.js as follows:

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
console.log(firebaseConfig);
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);

export default database;
```

I've also set all the corresponding environment variables in the Vercel dashboard using the same keys as in the firebaseConfig object.

However, when I deploy my project and log the firebaseConfig, all values are undefined. This issue is preventing my Firebase setup from functioning correctly in the deployed version of my application.

What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: did you redeploy after setting up your keys in vercel?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use `REACT_APP_` instead of `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};
```